# How to use try catch block if scrolling action is working sometimes nd sometimes not but it should perform next operation in mobile using java appium

Tags: scroll, try-catch, appium

How to use try catch block if scrolling action is working sometimes nd sometimes not but it should perform next operation in mobile using java appium

Code for try catch block with time limit if it is unable to scroll within that time limit it will execute next operation